# access a variable in a parent function from an iframe (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, iframe, parent

I have a javascript like the following on my main page: It just defines a variable

```
test1 = function(){
var bla= "bla";
}
```

In my iFrame, I have another javascript which only produces an alert like the following

```
alert(parent.test1.bl);
```

Unfortunately, the alert window appears but the content says "undefined". How can I read a variable from within a function in the parent window?

The funny part is that if I execute the alert at the parent window and call only the function from within the iFrame, the alert box pops up and the message is included. But it seems that it is not possible to read a variable from the parent.

Comment: I think you mean `parent.window.variable`?

Comment: The last part of your question is not clear. Here is what the alerts do: http://jsfiddle.net/rpsu8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions haven't properties, objects have. So you've to instantiate `test1()` before trying to use its properties.

```
test1 = function(){
    var bla= "bla";
    this.bl ="notbla";
}

alert(new test1().bl);
```

Notice the usage of the keyword `this` here, which refers to the newly created object, and makes `bl` a property, that can be read outside of the function. `bla` declared with `var` can't be seen outside of `test1()`, unless you won't create another property like `this.bl = bla;`

The "funny part" of your question really is unclear, definitely your `alert()` will show `undefined`, no matter where it's invoked.

[Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) at MDN.

Comment: Hi Teemu, Works like a charm!! :)